# NumberFormatException invalid int ""

Tags: java, android, logcat, numberformatexception

I am trying to take the input values from `EditText` and I want to save it to sqlite Database. I dont know how to use the logcat [also please explain how can I read the errors from the LogCat].

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.database;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    EditText first,last,age,classc;
    Button add,view;

    String FirstName;
    String LastName,Class;
    Integer Age;

    sqLit myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB = new sqLit(this);
        Link();
        xmlToVar();
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer flag=myDB.insertValue(FirstName, LastName, Class, Age);
                if (flag==1)
                {
                    Context context=getApplicationContext();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Record Added" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Context context=getApplicationContext();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Link()
    {
        first=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
        last=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
        classc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editClass);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        view=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewAll);
    }

    public void xmlToVar()
    {
        FirstName = first.getText().toString();
        LastName = last.getText().toString();
        Class = classc.getText().toString();
        Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    }


}
```

**sqLit.java:**

```
package com.example.database;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class sqLit extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DB_NAME="student12.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="class1";

    public static final String COL_1="ROLL NO";
    public static final String COL_2="First Name";
    public static final String COL_3="Last Name";
    public static final String COL_4="Class";
    public static final String COL_5="Age";




    public sqLit(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + "INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," + COL_2 + "TEXT," + COL_3 + "TEXT," + COL_4 + "TEXT," + COL_5 + "INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exist" + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Integer insertValue(String FirstName, String LastName, String Class, Integer Age)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentV = new ContentValues();
        contentV.put(COL_2, FirstName);
        contentV.put(COL_3, LastName);
        contentV.put(COL_4, Class);
        contentV.put(COL_5, Age);
        long isInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentV);
        if (isInserted == -1){
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
        }




}
```

Also, please explain how to use LogCat as I don't understand how to read it.

**LOGCAT:**

```
06-11 18:44:39.650: E/Trace(29536): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 18:44:39.660: D/AndroidRuntime(29536): Shutting down VM
06-11 18:44:39.660: W/dalvikvm(29536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f2b288)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:72)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at com.example.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-11 18:44:39.660: E/AndroidRuntime(29536):    ... 11 more
06-11 18:46:03.652: D/dalvikvm(30256): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-11 18:46:03.682: E/Trace(30256): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 18:46:03.712: D/AndroidRuntime(30256): Shutting down VM
06-11 18:46:03.712: W/dalvikvm(30256): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f2b288)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:73)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.example.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-11 18:46:03.712: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    ... 11 more
06-11 18:53:33.378: E/Trace(2383): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 18:53:33.408: D/AndroidRuntime(2383): Shutting down VM
06-11 18:53:33.408: W/dalvikvm(2383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f2b288)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:73)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at com.example.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-11 18:53:33.408: E/AndroidRuntime(2383):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your logCat & maybe somebody can help explain what is going on :)

Comment: every thing below `FATAL` is the stacktrace. It is the stack of method being executed when the crash happens. The `Cause by` section (there can be several, usually look at the last one) is the source of the error. It's the one you should be looking at. `at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:72)` is the first line that mentions your code. That's where your code causes the exception. (that a file and a line number). `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` is the actual exception. It tells you what went wrong. You are trying to parse `""` as an int.

Comment: The information that you posted from your logcat is called a stacktrace. For information about how to read it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors. In Android, you often have to scan passed the references to classes and methods from the Android API until you find the first mention of a class which you created yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

(after `FATAL EXCEPTION:`) tells us you are trying to parse an `int` but the value you are trying to parse is an empty `String`.

this line (the first that references your class) tells us which line it was

```
 at com.example.database.MainActivity.xmlToVar(MainActivity.java:72)
```

this is happening because you are calling it in `onCreate()` before the `EditText` has any value entered.

From the line above, we can see that the error happens in `MainActivity` in the method `xmlToVar` at line 72 which should be

```
Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
```

To solve this, you should call that method in an `onClick` or some event listener. You also should surround it in a `try/catch` or use some other validation checking.

You should read the following questions and their answers for more details:

[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

[java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726429/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int-in-android/16726453#16726453)

basically, read the error it gives you then look for the first line which mentions your class. Sometimes you need to read deeper but for basic errors that is usually enough.

> Also Please Explain how to use LogCat as I am 3 days Old Android Programmer. I never used Eclipse.

Note that the stacktrace isn't Eclipse or even Java/Android specific. You can get some sort of crash log like this in other languages/IDEs/Consoles

Comment: Hey Bro Thanks For your help.. but can you please tell me how did you find the problem??

Comment: The first part of my answer explains how I found it. Read the error which starts with `Caused by` then look for the line which references your class. It even gives you the line number. Here it is `MainActivity` at line 72. I saw that you were calling that line before the user had an opportunity to enter anything.

Comment: I could try to explain it better but I'm not sure which part doesn't make sense yet. Also, reading the above links should help you to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
```

`age.getText().toString()` equals `""` and which causes the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: The underlying problem being that `Integer.parseInt("")` throws `NumberFormatException` since it considers `""` as an invalid `Integer` (not even zero). Easy mistake we all did ^^