# My Application crashes immediately on launch on my AVD

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I have been trying my hands on this tax application on android and it crashes with errors I cant comprehend. I would like to get help on this as my previous answer could not stop the crash. Thanks so much for your time and help.

My Activity here
    package com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp;

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    double realSalary, taxPayable, sniit,firstTax,taxes, levelTax,taxable;
    EditText payable;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_salary);
        EditText allowance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_allowance);
        EditText incomeTax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IncTax_edit);
        EditText payable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.payable_edit);
        EditText totalTax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deduction_edit);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);


       double realSalary = Double.parseDouble(salary.getText().toString());
        double realAllowance = Double.parseDouble(allowance.getText().toString());

    }


   // final double taxRate = 0.055;
   // double tax;





        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

         calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {



           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                getSnit();

                getTaxable();

                computeTaxes();
            }
            // }

            public double getSnit() {


                sniit = realSalary * 0.055;


                return sniit;
            }

            // CALCULATING THE TAXABLE AFTER SNIIT

            public double getTaxable() {
                if (realSalary <= 216) {

                } else {
                    taxable = realSalary - sniit;
                }

                return taxable;

            }

            public double computeTaxes() {

                //SOLVING FOR THE SECOND LEVEL(2ND) LEVEL
                if (taxable > 216 && taxable <= 324) {
                    levelTax = taxable - 216;
                    firstTax = levelTax * 0.05;
                    System.out.println(levelTax);
                    taxes = 0.0 + firstTax;
                    payable.setText("" + taxes);

                    //SOLVING FOR THE THIRD(3RD) LEVEL
                } else if (taxable > 324 && taxable <= 475) {
                    levelTax = taxable - (216 + 108);
                    firstTax = levelTax * 0.10;
                    System.out.println(levelTax);
                    taxes = 0 + 5.40 + firstTax;
                    payable.setText("" + taxes);

                    //SOLVING FOR THE FOURTH(4TH) LEVEL
                } else if (taxable > 324 && taxable <= 3240) {
                    levelTax = taxable - (216 + 108 + 151);
                    firstTax = levelTax * 0.175;
                    System.out.println(levelTax);
                    taxes = 0 + 5.40 + 15.10 + firstTax;
                    payable.setText("" + taxes);

                    //SOLVING FOR THE FIFTH(5TH) LEVEL
                } else if (taxable > 3240) {
                    levelTax = taxable - (216 + 108 + 151 + 2765);
                    firstTax = levelTax * 0.25;
                    //System.out.println("First tax2 " + levelTax);

                    taxes = 0 + 5.40 + 15.10 + 483.88 + firstTax;
                    payable.setText("" + taxes);


                }
                return taxes;
            }


        });
    }
}


    My Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

    My errors
02-26 19:59:33.727 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.767 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 1 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.767 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 2 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.767 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 3 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.767 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 4 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.777 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 5 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.777 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 6 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 7 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 8 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 9 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 10 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 11 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 12 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.786 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 13 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 14 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 15 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 16 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 17 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 18 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 19 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 20 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 21 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.796 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 22 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 23 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 24 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 25 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 26 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 27 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 28 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 29 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 30 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 31 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 32 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.806 848-848/? W/dalvikvm: PR_CAPBSET_DROP 33 failed: Invalid argument. Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.
02-26 19:59:33.816 848-848/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-26 19:59:36.156 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-26 19:59:36.156 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-26 19:59:36.156 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17961: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-26 19:59:36.166 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:36.196 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-26 19:59:36.196 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17965: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-26 19:59:36.196 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:36.896 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-26 19:59:36.896 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-26 19:59:36.896 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:36.937 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-26 19:59:36.947 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-26 19:59:36.947 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:37.006 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
02-26 19:59:37.006 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18478: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
02-26 19:59:37.006 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
02-26 19:59:37.026 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
02-26 19:59:37.026 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18478: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
02-26 19:59:37.026 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
02-26 19:59:37.166 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
02-26 19:59:37.176 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 384: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-26 19:59:37.176 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:37.197 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
02-26 19:59:37.197 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-26 19:59:37.216 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-26 19:59:37.776 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 150K, 10% free 2716K/2992K, paused 97ms, total 106ms
02-26 19:59:37.806 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.377MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-26 19:59:37.907 848-857/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 8% free 3334K/3616K, paused 98ms, total 99ms
02-26 19:59:38.646 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-26 19:59:38.646 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465730)
02-26 19:59:39.016 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
                                                                                 at com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-26 20:04:39.726 848-848/com.example.lorlormensah.taxapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 848 SIG: 9
```

Comment: *" it crashes with errors I cant comprehend."* posting those error messages would help immensely. But your problem is probably trying to parse a presumably empty text box in `onCreate()` Probably something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30782688/1380752)

Comment: If you can't comprehend the errors that kind of a problem when it comes to debugging your own issues. Learn to read the errors and understand what they are trying to say. You can't just post it on stackoverflow to get the answer, otherwise you'll never learn to debug. Read the documentation, and add logs to help debugging. Be a developer. But your problem is very clear, it means the text your are immediately trying to parse is an empty string.. noted by Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" You can't possibly turn an empty string into a number for formatting...

Comment: Thanks, well noted @Jox Traex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realSalary and realAllowance doubles are causing the crash, check if they are empty

Try the following:

```
EditText payable;
Button calculate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_salary);
    EditText allowance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_allowance);
    EditText incomeTax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IncTax_edit);
    EditText payable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.payable_edit);
    EditText totalTax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deduction_edit);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);

          if(salary.getText().toString().length()>0)
         {
         double realSalary=Double.parseDouble(salary.getText().toString());
         }
          if(allowance.getText().toString().length()>0)
         {
          double realAllowance = Double.parseDouble(allowance.getText().toString());

         }
```