# App crashing when I press button

Tags: android

I have an app that asks for a users name, body weight, and weight lifted. The name is collected in a string and set to a textview no problem. However, when I try and collect a number for body weight and output it to a textview the app crashes. Also, I would like to post the logcat but it is a billion lines long. How can I change that so I can post what is applicable?

EDIT-Logcat added

Logcat

```
06-12 21:23:52.839      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:23:52.840      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:23:54.849    1613-1613/? E/NotificationTutorialService﹕ isScreenDisplayed(): false isHomeInForeground: false
06-12 21:23:54.871  28094-28094/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/com.motorola.calendarcommon.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:23:54.882  28094-28094/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/priv-app/Calendar.apk odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:23:55.233  28111-28111/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/android.test.runner.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:23:55.238  28111-28111/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/priv-app/CalendarProvider.apk odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:23:57.842      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:23:57.842      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:00.139  28138-28138/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/WfdCommon.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:00.140  28138-28138/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/com.motorola.frameworks.core.addon.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:00.172  28138-28138/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/am.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:00.178  28138-28138/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
06-12 21:24:00.385  28138-28138/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 21:24:00.385  28138-28138/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 21:24:01.120  28157-28157/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/WfdCommon.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:01.121  28157-28157/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/com.motorola.frameworks.core.addon.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:01.149  28157-28157/? E/dalvikvm﹕ /system/framework/am.jar odex has stale dependencies
06-12 21:24:01.158  28157-28157/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
06-12 21:24:01.316  28157-28157/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-12 21:24:01.316  28157-28157/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-12 21:24:02.087   8002-25516/? E/rsC++﹕ RS Message thread exiting.
06-12 21:24:02.844      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:02.845      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:07.846      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:07.846      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:12.748    2465-2481/? E/MC_BatteryUtils﹕ Coulomb counter file not found.
06-12 21:24:12.847      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:12.847      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:14.000  28167-28167/com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound, PID: 28167
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
        at com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18537)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 21:24:14.579    1613-1613/? E/NotificationTutorialService﹕ isScreenDisplayed(): false isHomeInForeground: false
06-12 21:24:17.849      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:17.849      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:22.851      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:22.851      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:27.853      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:27.853      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:32.869      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:32.870      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
06-12 21:24:37.872      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp 65000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max
06-12 21:24:37.872      415-453/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ set temp -128000 to name /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_max_hyst
```

Java File

```
package com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button calculate;
EditText inputname1;
EditText inputname2;
EditText inputbodyweight1;
TextView outputname1;
TextView outputname2;
TextView outputratio1;

int inputbodyweight1var = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    inputname1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputname1);
    inputname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputname2);
    inputbodyweight1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputbodyweight1);
    outputname1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputname1);
    outputname2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputname2);
    outputratio1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputratio1);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String inputname1var = inputname1.getText().toString();
                    String inputname2var = inputname2.getText().toString();
                    //String inputbodyweight1var = inputbodyweight1.getText().toString();
                    int inputbodyweight1var = Integer.parseInt(inputbodyweight1.getText().toString());
                    outputname1.setText(inputname1var);
                    outputname2.setText(inputname2var);
                    outputratio1.setText(inputbodyweight1var);


                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

XML File

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Body Weight"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/inputbodyweight1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weight Lifted"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inputname2"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Body Weight"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weight Lifted"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inputname1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_row="9"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RESET"
            android:layout_row="10"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/outputname1"
            android:layout_row="11"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/outputname2"
            android:layout_row="11"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ratio"
            android:id="@+id/outputratio1"
            android:layout_row="12"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ratio"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_row="12"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_row="13"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name is stronger than name by xx%"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_row="14"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *"I would like to post the logcat but it is a billion lines long. "* filter by "error" and it won't be a billion lines long

Comment: I have a feeling its because of setting an `int` as the text in the `setText` method

Comment: Luckily, this one was easy to spot. But, in the future, you need to include the stacktrace of the crash. Otherwise, you will likely receive down and close votes and it makes it much harder to get help.

Comment: thanks for the reference to the other question it solved my issue. and what do you mean by stacktrace? i am still learning all this stuff. ive been going off of youtube tutorials =\

Comment: [What is a stacktrace and how do I use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Now that you post your stacktrace, [this answer might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726429/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int-in-android/16726453#16726453). According to that, it is actually crashing before trying to set the text (though the original linked answer still needs to be applied). The EditText is empty when you try to parse it